# Please vote to make "Animal" tag synonymous with "Zoology" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

At some point someone made an [animal](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal) tag (now with 18 questions), which is silly given that we already have a [zoology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoology) tag (1048 questions).

I started a vote to make [animal](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal) a synonym of [zoology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoology), but it has garnered exactly <strike>0 attention or</strike> 1 vote<strike>s</strike>.

<strike>Let's just clean this up now...Please vote to make these two tags synonymous here:</strike>

<strike>https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/zoology/synonyms</strike>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your activity relating this issue has escaped my notice - my apologies. I merged [animal](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal) with [zoology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoology). The effects may take a while to become visible because of caching.

Comment: Have you recently made them synonyms? I already see [tag:animal-biology] mapping to zoology.

Comment: @BryanKrause - nope - my bad; they were already synonymized :) Cheers